# Why is my sub class considered a abstract class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, sdl, abstract

So for my next game I am creating classes to better the architecture of my game
I have  a abstract class called GameState and all GameStates (menus, windows, screen, the game itself) must inherit it to be added to the game but my BlankState which is a test of my GameState design gets me in trouble with the compiler as it is, for some reason, considered an abstract class, can anyone tell me why? I feel like I am missing something really obvious here.

Here is the GameState.h contents

```
#ifndef GUARD_GAMESTATE_H
#define GUARD_GAMESTATE_H

#include<SDL.h>

class Game;

class GameState {
protected:
    Game *m_pGame;
public:
    GameState( Game&  );

    virtual void load() = 0;

    virtual void handle_events( SDL_Event& events ) = 0;
    virtual void logic() = 0;
    virtual void draw() = 0;

    virtual void unload() = 0;

    virtual ~GameState() = 0;
};

class BlankState : public GameState {
private:
    SDL_Surface *background;

public:

    BlankState(Game& game);

    void load();
    void handle_events();

    void logic();

    void draw();

    void unload();

    ~BlankState();
};

#endif
```

And here is the GameState.cpp where I implement the GameState constructor and BlankStates inherited methods

```
#include"GameState.h"
#include"Game.h"
#include"AssetLoader.h"


GameState::GameState(Game& game) {
    m_pGame = &game;
    m_pGame->addState(this);
}




BlankState::BlankState(Game& game)
        :GameState(game)
    {}


void BlankState::load() {
        background = AssetLoader::loadImage("assets\background.png");
}

void BlankState::handle_events() {}

void BlankState::logic() {}

void BlankState::draw() {
        SDL_Rect lol;
        lol.x = 0;
        lol.y = 0;
        SDL_BlitSurface(background, NULL, m_pGame->getSurface(), &lol);
}

void BlankState::unload() {
        SDL_FreeSurface(background);
}

BlankState::~BlankState() {}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `void handle_events()` function in the derived class has a different signature than the `void handle_events(SDL_Event&)` function in the base class it is supposed to override.

The compiler is complaining because the derived class does not provide an implementation of the pure virtual function `void handle_events(SDL_Event&)` declared in the base class.

In other words, your derived class is abstract and the compiler correctly refuses to instantiate it.

As an additional remark, in C++11 you can use the contextual keyword `override` to explicitly state your intention of making a member function override a virtual function declared in the base class:

```
struct X
{
    virtual void foo(int) = 0;
};

struct Y : X
{
    virtual void foo(int) override { }
//                        ^^^^^^^^
//                        Makes it clear that this function is meant to
//                        override (and not just to hide) a virtual function 
//                        declared in the base class 
};

int main()
{
    Y y;
}
```

The purpose of this is that errors like the one you made could have been easily caught. Trying to `override` a function whose signature is not compatible with the signature of a virtual function in the base class would trigger a compilation error:

```
struct X
{
    virtual void foo(int) = 0;
};

struct Y : X
{
    virtual void foo() override { } // ERROR!
    //                 ^^^^^^^^
    //                 X::foo has an incompatible signature
};

int main()
{
    Y y;
}
```

Comment: OMG! Wow I just facepalmed so hard.... I can't believe I didn't see that... Thank you kind sir, for showing me the error of my ways. I knew it was something stupid like that, that is what I get for working so late at night and coming back to it in the morning

Comment: @Sbot: No problem, happens to everyone ;)